# Tensors In Continuum Mechanics And Artificial Intelligence

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, neural-networks, continuum-theory

I learned about tensors in a math course in grad school.  It was about the scalars, vectors, and higher-order tensors used in physics and differential geometry.  It talked about metric tensors, co-variance and contra-variance, with examples from continuum mechanics, general relativity, etc.

Thirty years later I'm reading about artificial intelligence, neural networks, and Tensor Flow.  It's clear to me that tensors in this context are higher-order extensions of 2D matrices from linear algebra.

The term tensor is overloaded for me.  My first thought always goes back to my first exposure from continuum mechanics.

Can someone explain the relationship between the two and suggest references for further reading about the connection?

Comment: In physics we deal mostly with tensor *fields* i.e. tensor valued functions on a manifold. It has become a habit to call those fields briefly *tensors* despite the fact that they are not just higher order "matrices".

Comment: In machine learning, a “tensor” is just a multidimensional array. It’s a much simpler object than what mathematicians call tensors.

Comment: In **Mathematics**, tensors are "Purely Algebraic Structures" with certain "useful" Properties. [ Professor Boaz Porat says "tensors are geometrical objects over vector spaces, whose coordinates obey certain laws of transformation under change of basis" ] In **Physics & other Sciences**, tensors are used to "represent" real world Properties like space-time, electromagnetic fields, gravitational fields, sub-atomic interactions & such. In **AI & ML**, tensors are "simply" collections of Data Points having Higher Dimensions. The 3 Interpretations have Different uses in Different contexts.

Comment: Such informative comments.  Thank you so much.  You don't need my approval of upvoted answers or earned points, but I'd be happy to upvote each of these if they were answers.  You have my undying admiration and appreciation, for what it's worth.

Comment: When you asked "Can someone explain the relationship between the two [three]", we can say (at a very high level) that *Mathematical* tensors have **"Core Properties" like covariant & contravariant coordinates, Symmetry & AntiSymmetry, etc** in addition to **"Normal Properties" like Metrics & Norms**. These can map to *Physical* field values at Points in Space-time even with various Physical transformations & these Properties are very much relevant. In *AI&ML*, the "Core Properties" are almost irrelevant & only the "Normal Properties" are generally used, Eg Comparing & measuring Similarity.

Comment: **tenso**r are like any other machine, they are either useful or a hazard, if they are useful is not my problem XD... *paraphrased from Blade Runner*

Comment: Not helpful or entertaining, but thanks for that.